# adding screen shots for iphone submission

Tags: iphone, submit, screenshot

just out of curiosity. i am thinking to add screen shots for my app subsission that are both oriented in landscape and portrait. does the store auto recognize these formats and apply them appropriately?

all the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does.